# Format of the header in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

Help please, I'm writing a Project (document class=book), and I'm using fancyhdr to change the format of the headers. My problem is that that format doesn't apply to the first pages of the table of contents. I mean, this is the header format in pages 2 & 3, which is the standard one:
[image]

while the header format in page 4 is the one I want (serif font, and no uppercase):

[image]

What can I do to have the format I want also in pages 2 and 3?

The first lines of my codes are:

```
\begin{document}
\afterpage{\markboth{\sf Índice}{\sf Índice}}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{\sf Índice}{\sf Índice}
\include{...}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please produce a proper [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that); not only does doing so often solve your problem all by itself, but it makes it much easier for others to help you.

As an aside, don't use `\sf` (along with `\bf`, `\it`, and so forth); these are deprecated font change commands.  Rather, you should be using `\sffamily` or `\textsf{text}`, because these commands fit into the LaTeX2e New Font Selection Scheme.

For your headers:  there's really no need to reinvent the wheel; you can try using a package to handle the headers.  `fancyhdr` is probably the most popular; it can what you want in very few lines:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[C]{\textsf{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Here, we begin by clearing current headers and footers with `\fancyfoot{}` and `\fancyhead{}`; that gives us a clean slate.  Then we set the page numbers on the left of even pages and the right of odd pages; then, in the middle of all pages, we put `\leftmark`, which is your chapter name in the `book` class.  We style it with `\textsf`, for sans serif type; and we use `\nouppercase` to prevent LaTeX from capitalizing the whole thing.  And that's it.

`fancyhdr` is really a superb package with excellent documentation; giving it a once-over will be quite helpful.

Comment: your "roll your own" version will fail on longer documents as the \markboth will come on the final page of the table of contents not the first. (`\afterpage` is in the core latex distribution, from package of same name)

Comment: So it will!  I'm just going to remove it, as it's a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I was already using fancyhdr, but imposing the serif font in another way. The command {\textsf{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}} solved my problem.

Comment: Glad it helps; but on TeX.SE, we usually don't post thank yous; upvoting or accepfing answers is our preferred way to say thanks.  Happy TeXing!